# how to find, using Delphi 7, that a (physical) disk with a specific number (0 .. n) exists in Windows?

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-7, disk

On a computer there are Disk 0, Disk 1,... (as we see in Computer management). These (physical) disks may have partitions or not, mounted or not and so on. I want to know if a Disk with a specific number exists on that computer (no matter what is on that disk).
This function has to work fine on any computer with Windows >= XP and it has to be as fast as possible (less than 1 second).
A simple enumeration 'A'..'Z' with GetDriveType and DeviceIoControl(...IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_DEVICE_NUMBER..)/DiskSize/DiskFree doesn't help if the disk doesn't have mounted volumes.
I'm using Delphi 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CreateFile()` to open `"\\.\PhysicalDriveX"` as the filename, where `X` is the desired number, and see if it succeeds or fails. Even if it fails, you can still check if the error is due to the device not being present versus not being accessible (which implies that it exists).

Comment: Thank you. It's a good idea. But what do you mean by "you can still check if the error is due to the device not being present versus not being accessible (which implies that it exists)"? Do I have to use other commands/functions if CreateFile returns INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE? If yes, which ones..?

Comment: [Read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858.aspx): "If the function fails, the return value is `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`. To get extended error information, call [`GetLastError()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360.aspx)". You can check for errors like `ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND` and `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`.

Comment: I already knew about GetLastError but I thought maybe there is a more elegant solution. Well, it will have to do.. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WMI
The query like 
select * FROM Win32_DiskDrive
get you the base information